# Dropbox - detect if dropbox is connected or not

Tags: windows, dropbox

Is there any way of detecting (like a registry boolean) whether or not Dropbox is connected?.

I have a problem where something causes Dropbox to spontaneously disconnect and it can't reconnect.  If I can craft something to keep monitoring the connection status I may be able to tie it to something else I am doing.

Prefereably without needing to delve into the Dropbox API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there currently isn't an official or supported way for programmatically checking the Dropbox desktop client status.

If you're having trouble with the Dropbox desktop client, you can contact Dropbox support:

https://www.dropbox.com/support